# Behaviour of the Spectral Weight Function $\frac{\sin^2{(\pi f t)}}{(\pi f)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, approximation

I'm looking into the properties of the so called spectral weight function $W_0 = \frac{\sin^2{(\pi f t)}}{(\pi f)^2}$. While not important for the question, this function is is encountered in the context of power spectral densities; it is basically a function that describes which parts of the power spectral density have the most weight in determining the mean squared value of a random variable at a certain point in time.

In any case, I stumbled upon it in the paper Decoherence of a superconducting qubit due to bias noise by Martinis et al. found at http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.67.094510 (equation 11, for those with access to the paper). There they write that the spectral weight function is constant for frequency $f \leq 1/t$ and decreases like $1/f^2$ at higher frequencies. At first I trusted this, but then I started looking into the function.

So first I plotted it for $t = 2$.
[image]

If the paper is to be believed, the function should be more or less constant up to f = 0.5. But it is not at all, not even close. Clearly something is off, but I do not understand what. Seeing as this is a published and peer reviewed paper, I am inclined to believe the mistake is on my side. My question is therefore if you can help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

The above plot is generated with a small piece of Mathematica code, which can be used to look at different $t$ values

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[Pi*f*t]^2/(Pi*f)^2, {f, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 4}}, GridLines -> {{1/t}, {}}, 
  ImageSize -> 500, FrameLabel -> {"f", "W(f)"}], {{t, 2}, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: If $f\ll1/t$ then $W_0(f)\approx t^2$ thus $W_0(f)\approx W_0(0)$. This is what "constant" refers to, here.(But don't ask me what $f\ll1/t$ for $t=2$ means, I am no physicist...)

Comment: @Did Thanks for that insight. As the person who answered below points out, it seems they are very liberal with their definitions.. As for the numbers, they have no physical meaning at this point. Typically one would take $f \approx 10^6 Hz$ and $t \approx 1 \mu s$, so the orders of magnitude are fine for inspecting the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is just the Fourier transform of the "triangle function" (Heaviside Lambda)
$$ f(x) = \left(1-\left|x\right|\right)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(-1,1)}(x) $$
that is compact supported. By the [Paley-Wiener theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem), $\widehat{f}$ is an entire function: since it is not constant (by just comparing the behaviour at $0$ and at $\pm\infty$), it cannot be constant on any open subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

The paper you mention probably uses *constant* in a (very!) improper way, by meaning *smooth and non-negative*.

Comment: Well, thanks for rigorously showing what I felt was the case. If anything it taught me about a new amazing theorem. But as for the paper.. Smooth and nonnegative, it is also smooth and nonnegative for $f > 1/t$, so I do not see what they mean. Of course visually there are two regimes, the decay from its initial value into oscillations which much lower amplitudes (excuse the language), but calling this constant.. Also saying that it behaves like $1/f^2$ for higher frequencies is a bit misleading if you mean that it is just basically 0.